# Convert calendar using iris

Tags: python, calendar, netcdf, netcdf4, python-iris

How can I convert a calendar with Iris? For example, converting a 'gregorian' calendar to '365_day'?

At the moment, I am doing

```
original_tcoord = cube_in.coords()[tcoord_idx]

tmp_time = cf_units.num2date(
    original_tcoord.points, 
    original_tcoord.units.name, 
    target_calendar,
)

new_time = cf_units.date2num(
    tmp_time, 
    original_tcoord.units.name, 
    target_calendar,
)
new_unit = cf_units.Unit(
    original_tcoord.units.name,
    calendar=target_calendar
)
new_tcoord = iris.coords.DimCoord(
    new_time,
    standard_name=original_tcoord.standard_name, 
    long_name=original_tcoord.long_name, 
    var_name=original_tcoord.var_name,
    units=new_unit,
)

cube_adjusted = cube_in.copy()
cube_adjusted.remove_coord('time')
cube_adjusted.add_dim_coord(
    new_tcoord, 
    tcoord_idx
)
```

Surely this isn't the fastest way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  If you add a `python` tag to your question, you will get syntax highlighting on your code snippet.  There is also a `python-iris` tag, which will make it easier for the Iris community to find your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can probably be done more simply, just by replacing the units on your existing coordinate:

```
tcoord = cube.coord('time')
tcoord.units = cf_units.Unit(tcoord.units.origin, calendar='gregorian')
```

this suggestion comes from Ruth Comer not me, but I am re-posting here as suggested.

Comment: Just seen this.  If you are converting between calendars with different numbers of days in the year, this method would create a change in the actual dates represented.  Whether that change is big enough to matter of course depends on the application!

Comment: Very true. As with all of these things where you are playing with incompatible calendars you need to be exceedingly careful!

Comment: In conclusion, the OP should have been asked WHY they wanted to change the calendar and then offering a more appropriate solution rather than coming up with simple mechanics without knowing the context.